# apex test class is failing on run

Tags: apex, unit-test

Can anyone help me out in writing test class for the below apex class.

I tried test class but when I was running the test then I am getting below error.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadTrigger: execution of AfterInsert
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadTrigger: execution of AfterInsert
>   caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003P000001CO0c0IAD; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]
>   Class.LeadTriggerHandler.afterInsertProcess: line 47, column 1
>   Trigger.LeadTrigger: line 3, column 1: []

Apex class:

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {

Static List<Lead> noParentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
Static List<Lead> parentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
Static List<Contact> insertConList = new List<Contact>();
Static List<Contact> insertConList1 = new List<Contact>();

public static void afterInsertProcess(List<Lead> leadList){

    List<hed__Relationship__c> insertRelationShipList = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
    List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
    List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList1 = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();


    for(Lead leadKey : leadList){
        if(leadKey.Parent_or_guardian__c == false){
            //list which contains Parent__c = false
            noParentLeadList.add(leadKey);
        }
        else{
            //list which contains Parent__c = true
           parentLeadList.add(leadKey);
        }
    }
   //Creates affiliation records if form has only student details
    if(noParentLeadList != null && noParentLeadList.size() > 0){
        Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap1 = createContactNoParent(noParentLeadList);
        Map<Id,String> LeadPrimaryProgram = new Map<Id,String>();
        set<Id> Possiblelead = new set<Id>();
        for(lead idkey :noParentLeadList){
            Possiblelead.add(idKey.Id);
        }

        //Map<Id,list<String>> secondaryPrimaryProgram = new Map<Id,list<String>>();
        for (Lead lead:[select Id,What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c from Lead where Id in :Possiblelead]){
            LeadPrimaryProgram.put(lead.id,lead.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);

        for(Id idKey : insertConMap1.keySet()){
            insertConList1.addAll(insertConMap1.get(idKey));
        }
        insert insertConList1;


        //Build Map of Accounts per Primary Program
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap2 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Name,SIS_Prog_Code__c from account where Name in : LeadPrimaryProgram.values() AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Academic_Program' and SIS_Prog_Code__c=null]){
            accNamesToIdsMap2.put(acc.Name,acc.Id);
        }

        for(Id IdKey : insertConMap1.keySet()){

            //creates affiliation record for primary program
            if (LeadPrimaryProgram.containsKey(idKey)){

                string PrimaryProgram=LeadPrimaryProgram.get(idKey);
                if (accNamesToIdsMap2.containsKey(PrimaryProgram)){          
                    Id AccountId=accNamesToIdsMap2.get(PrimaryProgram);
                        insertaffiliationList1.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= AccountId,
                                                            hed__Contact__c=insertConMap1.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                            hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                            hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
                }
            }

        }
        insert insertaffiliationList1;
        ConvertLeads1(insertConMap1);
    }
    //Creates relationship and affiliation records if form is filled by parent
    if(parentLeadList != null && parentLeadList.size() > 0){
        Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap = createContactParent(parentLeadList);
        Map<Id,String> LeadPrimaryProgram1 = new Map<Id,String>();
        set<Id> Possiblelead1 = new set<Id>();
        for(lead idkey :parentLeadList){
            Possiblelead1.add(idKey.Id);
        }
        for (Lead lead1:[select Id,What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c from Lead where Id in :Possiblelead1]){
            LeadPrimaryProgram1.put(lead1.id,lead1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
        }
        //contact insert operation
        for(Id idk : insertConMap.keySet()){
            insertConList.addAll(insertConMap.get(idk));
        }
        insert insertConList;

        //setting up inserted contact's Id in RelationShip__c object.
        for(Id IdKey : insertConMap.keySet()){
            hed__Relationship__c rel = new hed__Relationship__c(
                hed__Contact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                hed__RelatedContact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(1).Id,
                hed__Type__c = 'Parent'
            );
            insertRelationShipList.add(rel);
            //Creates affiliation record for primary program


                Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap1 = new Map<String,Id>();
            Id Accountrecordtype = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='Academic_Program'].Id;
                for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c,Name,SIS_Prog_Code__c from account where Name in : LeadPrimaryProgram1.values() AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Academic_Program' AND SIS_Prog_Code__c = null]){
                    accNamesToIdsMap1.put(acc.Name,acc.Id);
                }
            if (LeadPrimaryProgram1.containsKey(idKey)){

                string PrimaryProgram1=LeadPrimaryProgram1.get(idKey);
                if (accNamesToIdsMap1.containsKey(PrimaryProgram1)){          
                    Id AccountId1=accNamesToIdsMap1.get(PrimaryProgram1);
                    insertaffiliationList.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= AccountId1,
                                                            hed__Contact__c=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                            hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                            hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
                }
            }               
        }

        insert insertRelationShipList;
        insert insertaffiliationList;

        ConvertLeads(insertConMap);
    }
}
//method to convert the lead if lead has student details
public static void ConvertLeads1( Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap1){

    LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];

    Map<Id,Id> MapContactIdAccountId1 = new Map<Id,Id>(); //key: ContactID

    //Fetch AccountIds from database based on first contact for each Lead
    set<Id> PossibleContacts1 = new set<Id>();
    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap1.keySet()){
        PossibleContacts1.add(insertConMap1.get(IdKey).get(0).Id);
    }    

    for (Contact c:[select Id,AccountID from Contact where Id in :PossibleContacts1])
        MapContactIdAccountId1.put(c.id,c.AccountID);

    list<Database.LeadConvert> Leadconverts = new list<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap1.keySet()){

        string ContactId=insertConMap1.get(IdKey).get(0).Id;
        string AccountId=MapContactIdAccountId1.get(ContactId);

        Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        Leadconvert.setLeadId(IdKey);                
        Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
        Leadconvert.setAccountId(AccountId);
        Leadconvert.setContactId(ContactId);
        Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
        Leadconverts.add(LeadConvert);
    }

    list<Database.LeadConvertResult> ConvertResults = Database.convertLead(Leadconverts);


}
//method to convert the lead if lead has student and parent details
public static void ConvertLeads( Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap){

    LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];

    Map<Id,Id> MapContactIdAccountId = new Map<Id,Id>(); //key: ContactID

    //Fetch AccountIds from database based on first contact for each Lead
    set<Id> PossibleContacts = new set<Id>();
    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap.keySet()){
        PossibleContacts.add(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id);
    }    

    for (Contact c:[select Id,AccountID from Contact where Id in :PossibleContacts])
        MapContactIdAccountId.put(c.id,c.AccountID);

    list<Database.LeadConvert> Leadconverts = new list<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap.keySet()){

        string ContactId=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id;
        string AccountId=MapContactIdAccountId.get(ContactId);

        Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        Leadconvert.setLeadId(IdKey);                
        Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
        Leadconvert.setAccountId(AccountId);
        Leadconvert.setContactId(ContactId);
        Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
        Leadconverts.add(LeadConvert);
    }

    list<Database.LeadConvertResult> ConvertResults = Database.convertLead(Leadconverts);


}

public static Map<Id,List<Contact>> createContactParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){
    Id Studentrecordtype = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='Lead'].Id;
    Id Parentrecordtype = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='Parent'].Id;

    Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    List<Contact> conList=null;


    for(Lead tmpLead : incomingLeadList){
        string pickValuesStr;
        if(tmpLead.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        List<string> pickvalues = tmpLead.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';');
        for(string str : pickvalues){
            if(string.isBlank(pickvaluesStr)){
                pickvaluesStr = str;
            }
            else{
                pickvaluesStr= pickvaluesStr+';'+str;
            }
        }
       }
            conList = new List<Contact>();
        Contact con = new Contact(
                LastName = tmpLead.LastName, 
                FirstName = tmpLead.FirstName,
                Email = tmpLead.Email,
                RecordTypeId = Studentrecordtype,
                );
            conList.add(con);

            con = new Contact(
                LastName = tmpLead.Parent_Last_Name__c,
                FirstName = tmpLead.Parent_First_Name__c,
                Email = tmpLead.Parent_Email__c,
                RecordTypeId = Parentrecordtype,
                Parent_is_alumni__c = tmpLead.Parent_is_alumni__c,
                Parent_Country_of_Residence__c = tmpLead.Parent_Country_of_Residence__c
            );
            conList.add(con);           
            contactMap.put(tmpLead.id, conList);
    }
    return contactMap;
}

public static Map<Id,List<Contact>> createContactNoParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap1 = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    Id Studentrecordtype = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='Lead'].Id;
    Id Parentrecordtype = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='Parent'].Id;

    List<Contact> contactList = null;
    for(Lead ldKey : incomingLeadList){
     string pickValuesStr1;
    if(ldKey.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){               

    List<string> pickvalues = ldKey.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';');
        for(string str1 : pickvalues){
            if(string.isBlank(pickvaluesStr1)){
                pickvaluesStr1 = str1;
            }
            else{
                pickvaluesStr1= pickvaluesStr1+';'+str1;
            }
        }
    }
        contactList = new List<Contact>();
        Contact con = new Contact(
            LastName = ldKey.LastName,
            FirstName = ldKey.FirstName,
            Email =ldKey.Email,
            RecordTypeId = Studentrecordtype,
        );
        contactList.add(con);
        contactMap1.put(ldKey.Id, contactList);
    }
    return contactMap1;
}   
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
   public class TestContactCreationFromLead {

   static testMethod void ContactCreationFromLeadtrigger(){
  List<Lead> parentleadinsert = new List<Lead>();
Account acc = new Account(Name='Accounting and Finance',Pardot_Program_Name__c='Accounting and Finance');
insert acc;
Account acc1 = new Account(Name='Accounting and Finance',Pardot_Program_Name__c='Disability Studies');
insert acc1;
test.startTest();
  Lead le1 = new Lead(LastName='Lead1234', Email='Lead1@gtg4.com', Status='New',Company='Test',Expected_Year_of_Enrolment__c=2028,What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c='Accounting and Finance',Other_Programs_of_Interest__c='Accounting and Finance',Parent_or_guardian__c=false);
  insert le1;
Lead l1 = new Lead(Id=le1.Id,LastName='Lead245', Email='Lead1@g234.com', Status='New',Company='Test',Expected_Year_of_Enrolment__c=2028,What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c='Accounting and Finance',Other_Programs_of_Interest__c='Accounting and Finance',Parent_First_Name__c='ParentF',Parent_Last_Name__c='ParentL',Parent_Email__c='Parentemail@g.in',Parent_or_guardian__c=true); 
update l1;
  if(le1.Parent_or_guardian__c==false){
Contact c = new Contact(AccountId=acc.Id,LastName=le1.LastName,Email=le1.Email);
insert C;
   hed__Affiliation__c hed = new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c=acc.Id,hed__Contact__c=c.Id,hed__Primary__c=true);
    insert hed;
   hed__Affiliation__c hed1 = new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c=acc1.Id,hed__Contact__c=c.Id,hed__Primary__c=false);
    insert hed1;
}
    Contact c1= new Contact(AccountId=acc.Id,LastName=l1.LastName,Email=l1.Email);
    update c1;
    Contact c2= new Contact(AccountId=acc.Id,LastName=l1.Parent_Last_Name__c,FirstName=l1.Parent_First_Name__c,Email=l1.Parent_Email__c);
    update c2;
    hed__Affiliation__c hed2 = new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c=acc.Id,hed__Contact__c=c1.Id,hed__Primary__c=true);
    update hed2;
    hed__Affiliation__c hed3 = new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c=acc1.Id,hed__Contact__c=c1.Id,hed__Primary__c=false);
    update hed3;
    hed__Relationship__c rel = new hed__Relationship__c(hed__Contact__c=c1.Id,hed__RelatedContact__c=c2.Id,hed__Type__c='Parent');
    update rel;
le1 = [SELECT ConvertedAccountId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :le1.Id];
      System.assertNotEquals( le1.ConvertedAccountId, 'Expected lead to be converted.');
       l1 = [SELECT ConvertedAccountId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :l1.Id];
     System.assertNotEquals( l1.ConvertedAccountId, 'Expected lead to be converted.');
  test.stopTest();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please check this dml statement insert ConList1.My guess would be you're class is firing multiple times Please check recursive trigger concept

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere that you have code like the following, you have a problem:

```
for(Id idKey : insertConMap1.keySet()){
    insertConList1.addAll(insertConMap1.get(idKey));
}
insert insertConList1;
```

If you look at the error you're getting, it boils down to "we can't insert this record, because it already has an ID".

In this particular instance, your map is keyed on `Id`, meaning all of the records inside of it will already have an Id.

This also seems like a very roundabout way to say `insert insertConMap1.values()`.

You need to take a few steps back and re-evaluate your logic here. At the very least, you'll need to find all of the instances where you use a similar pattern and replace them with an `update` operation instead of using `insert`.

Comment: Hello Derek F, I have only two instances where I am using the for loop you mentioned, I am using "insertConMap1.get(idKey" in one loop and "insertConMap.get(idKey" in another loop, in both cases I need to insert the contacts basically

Comment: Hello Derek, I updated my test class in question, I changed to update now but now i am getting below error >System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve it, I was inserting leads outside the starttest command, when I inserted leads inside starttest loop then it worked.